# Using Nifi ExecuteSQLRecord with parameterized SQL statements?

Tags: oracle, apache-nifi

Can someone explain or show how Nifi's ExecuteSQLRecord would work with parameters? The documentation says:

> If it is triggered by an incoming FlowFile, then attributes of that FlowFile will be available when evaluating the select query, and the query may use the ? to escape parameters.  In this case, the parameters to use must exist as FlowFile attributes with the naming convention sql.args.N.type and sql.args.N.value,
> where N is a positive integer. The sql.args.N.type is expected  to be a number indicating the JDBC Type.

I've been able to use the HandleHttpRequest, ExtractText, to make this query work. `curl -d "select * from MY_TABLE WHERE NAME = '1234'" http://localhost:5555`

I'm unsure how I would update the ExecuteSQLRecord to make it work with parameters to avoid a sql injections.

[image]

Would I replace the 'test' with a ? and extract the attributes with another processor? I wish there was an example.

Answer (score 2):

The query should be `select * from MY_TABLE where NAME = '?'`, and then incoming flowfiles will need to have the following attributes (from your example):

- `sql.args.1.type`: `varchar`
- `sql.args.1.value`: `1234`

For multiple parameters, it would follow this general pattern:

Query: `select * from MY_TABLE where NAME = '?' and OTHER_COL = '?' ...`

Flowfile attributes:

- `sql.args.1.type`: `varchar`
- `sql.args.1.value`: `First Last`
- `sql.args.2.type`: `integer`
- `sql.args.2.value`: `1234`

...

Comment: FWIW as of 1.11.4 https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-standard-nar/1.11.4/org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.ExecuteSQLRecord/index.html 

I had to use number values in the type attributes from https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/constant-values.html#java.sql.Types.ARRAY

so

 - `sql.args.1.type`: `12`
 - `sql.args.2.type`: `4`

Additionally, for Postgres, I needed to remove the single quotes from around the question mark so `select * from MY_TABLE where NAME = ? and OTHER_COL = ? `