# how to insert values in queue of nifi

Tags: sql, apache-nifi

[image: flow]

In case of imgae, only one single value(number) in second queue.

[image]

How can I insert data(value in queue) into table use SQL?

"insert into table values (   queue    )"

I want insert  1321   into table in this case.

Which variable or parameter can I use?

insert into table values  ( ${???????})

Thank you for your answer.

Comment: Have you seen this post and converted the example for insert statement? https://stackoverflow.com/a/63344305/2308683 The docs explain how to use args from **FlowFiles**, they're not called queues here https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-standard-nar/1.5.0/org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.ExecuteSQL/index.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In EvaluateJsonPath set parameter `flowfile-content = flowfile-attribute`

And set dynamic parameter with name `sql.args.1.value` and value with current jsonpath.

After this change the number that you see in content should appear in attribute with corresponding name.

Then set query to `insert into TableName values (?)`

During execution nifi will use `sql.args.1.value` instead of first `?`

Probably you need to set a numeric type of the value #1 with attribute `sql.args.1.type=2` - use Updateattributes processor for this. But I think it's optional for a simple type..